# delete operator doesn't seem to call global operator delete overload

Tags: c++

The output of the following program is

```
Global new
```

The code doesn't seem to call `operator delete`. Invoking `::operator delete` directly does call the function, but using the regular `delete` operator doesn't.

I assume it's related to the compiler optimizing away the `delete` call. I tried to test that by placing all sorts of code after the `delete` call, including resetting the `a` pointer to a different expression. I would assume that would make the compiler insert the `delete`, because otherwise we have a leak. Still - the same result.

So, I assume this is the compiler eliminating an indeed unnecessary call to `delete` by rather sophisticated analysis. But, I'd like to be sure. I attempted reading the output assembly from `g++`, but I wasn't able to understand it.

Please explain this phenomenon.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    cout << "Global new\n";
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* p) {
    cout << "Global delete\n";
    free(p);
}

void f() {
    int* x = new int;
    delete x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

I use Mingw-w64 on Windows 7, `g++ std=c++17` version 9.3.0.

EDIT:

People have responded it does produce the expected output on their machines. So possibly a compiler bug on my machine?

Output assembly if anyone's interested:

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
.lcomm _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "Global new\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _Znwy
    .def    _Znwy;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _Znwy
_Znwy:
.LFB1882:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    16(%rbp), %rcx
    call    malloc
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC1:
    .ascii "Global delete\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _ZdlPv
    .def    _ZdlPv; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _ZdlPv
_ZdlPv:
.LFB1883:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movq    %rcx, 16(%rbp)
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdx
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movq    16(%rbp), %rcx
    call    free
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .globl  _Z1fv
    .def    _Z1fv;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _Z1fv
_Z1fv:
.LFB1884:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    $4, %ecx
    call    _Znwy
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .L6
    movl    $4, %edx
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    _ZdlPvy
.L6:
    nop
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
.LFB1885:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp)
    call    __main
    call    _Z1fv
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    __tcf_0;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   __tcf_0
__tcf_0:
.LFB2377:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii;    .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB2376:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, 24(%rbp)
    cmpl    $1, 16(%rbp)
    jne .L12
    cmpl    $65535, 24(%rbp)
    jne .L12
    leaq    _ZStL8__ioinit(%rip), %rcx
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    leaq    __tcf_0(%rip), %rcx
    call    atexit
.L12:
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .def    _GLOBAL__sub_I__Znwy;   .scl    3;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   _GLOBAL__sub_I__Znwy
_GLOBAL__sub_I__Znwy:
.LFB2378:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $32, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 32
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    $65535, %edx
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .ctors,"w"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I__Znwy
    .ident  "GCC: (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.3.0"
    .def    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    malloc; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    free;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZdlPvy;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    atexit; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout, "dr"
    .globl  .refptr._ZSt4cout
    .linkonce   discard
.refptr._ZSt4cout:
    .quad   _ZSt4cout
```

Comment: I get the expected output (and a few warnings).

Comment: I got both Global new and Global Delete as well.  Seem like it's working as expected.  Using VS2017.  Maybe some optimization, I'll try with a release build and let you know .

Comment: @noobius @Xilpex I just tested it again, I still only get `Global new`. Just added at the bottom the compiler information. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug perhaps. It WFM with `gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)` - I receive both the 'new' and 'delete' messages compiled with default parameters.

Comment: Got the [expected output](https://godbolt.org/z/UyTPSb) too

Comment: To check weather the calls to `new` and `delete` are optimized away, you can compile with `-O0` option. For me, it doesn't make a difference. You don't need to fully understand the whole assembly. There will be a section for your function `f`, and inside this section you will see two `call`s to operators new and delete.

Comment: @flowit Interesting, compiling with `-O0` also outputs the same thing. I tried looking for a `call` to new and delete in the assembly. However the words `new` and `delete` only appear as the string literals for the `cout` calls.

Comment: The only think I can imagine is if `malloc` is failing. There is a branch in that assembly ...

Comment: @AvivCohn btw, you might look at `c++filt` to make sense of the mangled names. Some other tools also have support for demangling built-in, but you have to manually activate it.

Comment: Do you have the answer now? I encounter exactly the same problem. Tried similar code on both Windows and Linux, I use Visual C++, GNU C++ and Clang C++ to build the same code, and only GNU C++ on Windows has this problem. All other compilers work just as expected. The version of the GNU C++ on Windows is 10.2.0.

Comment: I just found this. If use -Os to optimize it, it won't call global op `new` as well. This is obviously a bug or a feature of GNU C++, because compilers apparently don't like global op `new` and `delete` to be redefined. If override them, most compilers, e.g. Clang C++, Visual C++, will give compile-time warning.